# group a list and only get distinct values when input is a list

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I need some help with the following:

I have a list where all the duplicate entries need to be removed from and I cant seem to get the right linq query. now the list itself contains a string and a list of strings as parameters.

see the code snippets:

the list is created from this class

```
public class SD
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public List<string> To { get; set; }
}
```

the input of the list may look like this:

```
var unsortedList = new List<SD>
{
    new SD {From = "a", To = new List<string>{ "b" } },
    new SD {From = "b", To = new List<string>{ "a" } },
    new SD {From = "a", To = new List<string>{ "b", "c" } },
    new SD {From = "a", To = new List<string>{ "b" } },
    new SD {From = "a", To = new List<string>{ "c" } },
};
```

Before the To in the class was a list and just was a string the below code was working perfect. It would return 4 entries as entry 1 and 4 are equal (and off course the 3rd entry would only have one string).

```
var sortedList = unsortedList.GroupBy(x => new { x.From, x.To }).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();
```

I've been playing around with orderby, group and hashsets but none seems to work.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with current code?

Comment: In the example code, the group by will not work on the To list. So every entry in the SD list is marked as unique with the result that all entry's are returned. With the solution that RoadRunner provided I get the correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join `To` list into string and use it as part of key selector in [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) method. Then select the first item in every group to get a list of `SD` items without duplicates

```cs
var sortedList = unsortedList.GroupBy(x => new {x.From, To = string.Join(",", x.To)})
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in sortedList) 
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.From} {string.Join(",", item.To)}");
```

It'll produce the following output

```
a b
b a
a b,c
a c
```

Comment: Thats a nice solution. Didn't think of using `To` as a string key. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` here:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<SD>
{
    public bool Equals(SD x, SD y)
    {
        return x.From == y.From && x.To.SequenceEqual(y.To);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SD obj)
    {
        return obj.From.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then apply this comparer to [`Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8) to remove duplicates:

```
var noDuplicates = unsortedList.Distinct(new MyComparer());

foreach (var item in noDuplicates)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"From={item.From} To={string.Join(", ", item.To)}");
}

// From=a To=b
// From=b To=a
// From=a To=b, c
// From=a To=c
```